# Parsing XML Data Into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am struggling with importing XML Data into SQL Server 2016. I have tried a few things, but keep either getting errors or just no data is returned.

I have this XML Data stored in an XML file (limited the data because it is pretty sensitive:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Details_-_EXPORT_-_Workplace">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Active_Status>0</wd:Active_Status>
        <wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name>Charlotte</wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name>
        <wd:Position>Executive Housekeeper I</wd:Position>
        <wd:Worker_Management_Level>Supervisor</wd:Worker_Management_Level>
        <wd:continuous_service_date>1979-04-29-08:00</wd:continuous_service_date>
        <wd:Hire_Date>1979-04-29-08:00</wd:Hire_Date>
        <wd:termination_date>2019-12-22-08:00</wd:termination_date>
        <wd:Anniversary_Month>04</wd:Anniversary_Month>
        <wd:Years_of_Service>40</wd:Years_of_Service>
        <wd:Employee_Type>Hotel</wd:Employee_Type>
        <wd:Time_Type>Full Time</wd:Time_Type>
        <wd:Pay_Rate_Type>Salary</wd:Pay_Rate_Type>
        <wd:Marital_Status>Single</wd:Marital_Status>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Active_Status>0</wd:Active_Status>
        <wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name>Robert</wd:Legal_Name_-_First_Name>
        <wd:Cost_Center_-_Name>Electronics</wd:Cost_Center_-_Name>
        <wd:Work_Address_-_State_Province>Missouri</wd:Work_Address_-_State_Province>
        <wd:Position>Manager Of Voice Networks</wd:Position>
        <wd:Worker_Management_Level>Manager</wd:Worker_Management_Level>
        <wd:continuous_service_date>1980-02-25-08:00</wd:continuous_service_date>
        <wd:Hire_Date>1980-02-25-08:00</wd:Hire_Date>
        <wd:termination_date>2020-03-22-07:00</wd:termination_date>
        <wd:Anniversary_Month>02</wd:Anniversary_Month>
        <wd:Years_of_Service>40</wd:Years_of_Service>
        <wd:Employee_Type>Corporate</wd:Employee_Type>
        <wd:Time_Type>Full Time</wd:Time_Type>
        <wd:Pay_Rate_Type>Salary</wd:Pay_Rate_Type>
        <wd:Marital_Status>Married</wd:Marital_Status>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

I have this code that I am trying to use, but keep getting just an empty result:

```
SELECT  
    XMLCol.ReportEntry.query('Active_Status').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS ActiveStatus
FROM
    (SELECT 
         CAST(XMLCol AS XML)
     FROM 
         OPENROWSET(BULK '\\afcn2011\root\DATA\VisualCron\Employee Export\EmployeeExport.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(XMLCol)
    ) AS T(XMLCol)
CROSS APPLY 
    XMLCol.nodes('Report_Data/Report_Entry') AS XMLCol(ReportEntry);
```

Comment: Because you are ignoring XML namespaces.

Comment: See [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-ver15) on xml namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to respect and include the XML namespace defined in your document.

Try something like this:

```
-- define the namespace and give it a prefix - here "wd"
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Details_-_EXPORT_-_Workplace' as wd)
SELECT  
    -- you need to include namespace prefix when referring to the XML element
    -- also: is "VARCHAR(20)" really the best datatype?? Looks more like "INT" to me ...
    XMLCol.ReportEntry.value('(wd:Active_Status/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS ActiveStatus
FROM
    (SELECT 
         CAST(XMLCol AS XML)
     FROM 
         OPENROWSET(BULK '\\afcn2011\root\DATA\VisualCron\Employee Export\EmployeeExport.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(XMLCol)
    ) AS T(XMLCol)
CROSS APPLY 
    -- you need to include namespace prefix in your XPath expression
    XMLCol.nodes('/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry') AS XMLCol(ReportEntry);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to get it fixed with this.

And yes, VARCHAR(20) is incorrect, it is actually a BIT, but it is an old legacy dataset that someone decided that NVARCHAR(100) was good for literally everything...